# unit converter with dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to build an unit converter and so far I did this:
`units = {"mm": {"mm": 1, "cm": 1 / 10, "m": 1 / 1000, "km": 1 / 1000000}, "cm": {"mm": 10, "cm": 1, "m": 1 / 100, "km": 1 / 100000}, "m": {"mm": 1000, "cm": 100, "m": 1, "km": 1 / 1000}, "km": {"mm": 1000000, "cm": 100000, "m": 1000, "km": 1}}`

But I am stuck what my next steps should be, any advice will be appreciated as I use for first time a dictionary and I am not sure how to use it properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more context, how to you want to use your converter ? On what kind of data?

Comment: look up how to make a unit converter with python on youtube... DOn't ask everybody to do your homework for you.

Comment: For example the user will enter 10 mm and the program should it convert to cm or m or km and so on. I did it with if statement but no idea how to do it with dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked on your base, try it

```
def unit_conversion(data, unit_to):
    units = {
        "mm": {"mm": 1, "cm": 1 / 10, "m": 1 / 1000, "km": 1 / 1000000},
        "cm": {"mm": 10, "cm": 1, "m": 1 / 100, "km": 1 / 100000},
        "m": {"mm": 1000, "cm": 100, "m": 1, "km": 1 / 1000},
        "km": {"mm": 1000000, "cm": 100000, "m": 1000, "km": 1}
    }

    unit = "".join([item for item in data if item in "cmk"])
    num = data.rstrip(unit).strip()
    return "{}{}".format(float(num) * units.get(unit).get(unit_to), unit_to)


print(unit_conversion("12341cm", "km"))
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I will debug it and read more about it, thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Scale conversion is independent from the unit of measure. You could work with Kelvin, Watts, eVolts and the underlying principle is the same. What is important is the *difference* between scale prefix (hence no need of nested dictionaries).

If you need to deal with unit of lengths, then the meter is right choice. You can convert the output to string and append to it the unit of measure.

```
metric_prefix = { # just a sample of prefix
'G': 9,   # giga
'M': 6,   # mega
'k': 3,   # kilo
'h': 2,   # hecto
'da': 1,  # deca
'': 0,    # default !
'd': -1,  # deci
'c': -2,  # centi
'm': -3,  # milli
'μ': -6,  # micro
'n': -9   # nano
}

def scale_converter(value: float, scale: str, new_scale: str) -> float:
    gap = metric_prefix[scale] - metric_prefix[new_scale]
    return value * 10**gap
    

print(scale_converter(value=123, scale='k', new_scale=''))
#123000
print(scale_converter(123, 'c', new_scale=''))
#1.23
print(scale_converter(123, 'M', new_scale='m'))
123000000000


# with unit of measure
value, scale, new_scale, unit = 123, 'n', 'm', 'm'
new_value = scale_converter(value, scale, new_scale)

print(f'conversion: {value} {scale} {unit} --> {new_value} {new_scale} {unit}')
# conversion: 123 n m --> 0.00012299999999999998 m m
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I got the idea for nested dictionaries, I will try to understand your solution.

Comment: @The_witcher10 [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). In case of bytes than change the base, `2**gap` instead of `10**gap`